# Components necessary to automate hand crank

Tags: arduino, motor, bluetooth, home-automation

I'd like to automate a simple crank on a rotating hex bolt thingy so I don't have to manually turn the lever/knob.

I was planning on

bluetooth module -> Arduino (or some easily programmable MC) -> motor -> hex bit

as the component diagram.

I can learn the Arduino programming, etc I'm sure, but I wanted your help with the motor:

1. I think the torque required is a pretty important factor - the manual rotating handle has a ~3in length arm, and requires a hefty deal of force (scientific, I know, but I'm not sure how to measure this short of a force meter) to turn clockwise, but much less while rotating counter-clockwise.
2. I'd like to be able to have the motor sustain this at 5+ revs/sec (the more the better).
3. The whole setup should be as quiet as possible as it will run in an office environment

Thanks for your help!

P.S. Any improvements to / ideas for the entire scenario (raise lower my adjustable height desk without rotating the hand crank) are certainly welcome - this isn't mission critical!

Comment: I'm thinking, put a power screwdriver on there. Are you OK with having to hold the `up` or `down` buttons until the desk reaches the desired height? If so, you can skip the rest of the electronics entirely.

Comment: @jwygralak67 that's definitely one way to do it, but I thought that with the holidays coming and all my vacation time used up, I might try to have some fun with this! If it turns out to be too complicated getting the arduino to work though, that's probably what I can end up doing

Comment: Fun is a whole different approach. I would add a height sensor so you could use your smart phone (via the bluetooth) to command it to go to a preset height and stop automatically. The arduino could receive a command via bluetooth, read the height sensor, then power the motor to move the desk to the desired height. (I'd still consider a power screwdriver.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 rotations per second is a *lot*. I wouldn't be surprised if the C nut and ACME rod that probably drives your desk were not actually rated for that speed.

To get a reasonable amount of torque at, say, 1 revolution per second, you'd use an electric gearmotor. Pololu.com has a number of good choices. For example, the 37D 5A gearmotor at 100:1 gearing will run at 100 rpm, giving you 200 oz.in of torque (which is a fair bit -- probably more than you're cranking on a 3 inch lever.)
http://www.pololu.com/product/1106

You also need a way of mechanically coupling the 6mm D-shaft output to the hex bolt, some way of fastening the motor so it doesn't counter-spin, and some way to drive the motor.
Driving the motor means a 5A/12V power supply, and an H-bridge that can take 10A/24V to safely withstand the worst-case reversing-direction transients. A Pololu simple motor controller, or an Orion Robotics RoboClaw, or a Dimension Engineering Sabretooth, would be a reasonable hobby-level choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yeah thinking more deeply, I guess 5rps is quite a bit.

The motor you've linked to seems fine (though I'll get the version with the encoder for later enhancements), but I'm a little confused about the driving - based on your suggestions, I'm looking at http://www.pololu.com/product/1376 . Is that all I need in addition to the motor (except mechanical couplings of course). Are you saying that instantaneously reversing direction is the reason for the double current/power H bridge? Writing logic that never does that would suffice, correct? (just for my understanding)

Comment: The problem is that, when a motor changes speed or direction, it generates a higher counter-voltage than what you feed it. In the worst case, this will be twice your regular supply voltage (unless you drive the motor by force faster than it spins by voltage,) so if you spec the motor controller for twice the voltage you feed the motor, you are "safe." It *may* work with a smaller driver, if you drive it carefully, but probably not at the "robust enough for other family members" level. And, yes, that motor controller, plus some wiring, lets you drive motor from Arduino.